# Arithmetic Coding Implementation Performance Boost

Tags: math, encoding, compression

I'm working on optimizing my Arithmetic Compression Implementation. I've included a basic arithmetic encoding algorithm below:

```
lower bound = 0
upper bound = 1

while there are still symbols to encode
  current range = upper bound - lower bound
  upper bound = lower bound + (current range × upper bound of new symbol)
  lower bound = lower bound + (current range × lower bound of new symbol)
end while
```

I have an idea to round my values, but to do so, the calculation of the upper bound CANNOT use the lower bound value. I can't figure out how to do that.

More information: I plan on rounding the lower bound up, narrowing the range, thus retaining precision, all the while making my number have less digits. Then rounding my upper bound lower in the same way.
However, the calculation of the upper bound makes it so it increases if we increase the value of the lower bound, thus making the algorithm incorrect.

My question is: How can I calculate the upper bound, without using the value of the lower bound?

Comment: Are you deliberately leaving the shift/scale operation out of your pseudocode, or do you plan to retain all your data in memory until your the compression is finished?  I would think that the kind of rounding you need depends on the details of how you handle this...

Comment: I just read up on the shifting of bits. But I'm using BigDecimals in my Java implementation, and I'm finding it difficult to only operate on the most significant bits. Would you know how I can do that in Java with BigDecimals?

Comment: I recommend using a `long` instead.

Comment: Hmm.. do you know if I'll be able to freely use shifting using a long?

Comment: Since you are using Java, you can use the unsigned right-shift operator `>>>` to do the kind of shifting you need for arithmetic compression.

Comment: I'm doing some research into this to see if I can't try and use it instead. Thank you for all your help, I'll update you soon. If you could provide any code I'd also be very grateful.

Comment: Oops, the actual main operator you will need most for arithmetic compression is the left-shift operator `<<`.  However, depending on how you implement your math, knowing about the unsigned right-shift operator could be useful, too...

Answer (score 0):

In regard to shifting your string to left , use: string.substring(1)